# How we can read @State variable from other struct in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to know if there is simple or proper way to read a State variable value from a different View, I know the usage of .onChange or Binding or ObservableObject(class) and ..., but I like to know is there any other better way?

For example in this code I have a View called TextView which has a State value, and I am calling this View inside my ContentView, Now I put a Text in my ContentView which I want to read the State Value of TextView. Is there a spacial method for this job?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var readStringOfTextView: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextView()

        Text(readStringOfTextView)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @State var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"

    var body: some View {
        Text(stringOfText)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The entire point of State is that it's internal to a View. If you're trying to read it elsewhere, something has gone wrong in your design. The tool you want in this case is `@Binding`. ContentView should pass a Binding to TextView. Any changes in TextView will be seen by ContentView (in your example, this doesn't make sense, because `stringOfText` can't change, but I assume that the rest of your code changes it somehow). In your example, that would look something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var readStringOfTextView: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextView(stringOfText: $readStringOfTextView)
        Text(readStringOfTextView)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @Binding var stringOfText : String

    var body: some View {
        Text(stringOfText)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .onAppear {
                stringOfText = "Hello, world!"
            }
    }
}
```

In is possible to directly pass data up the view hierarchy using Preferences, but it's much more complicated, and not the right tool for the problem you've described. Even so, this is what it would look like:

- Create a PreferenceKey to pass the data
- Set the PreferenceKey in the child view(s) using `.preference`
- Read the PreferenceKey in the parent view using `.onPreferenceChange` or `.overlayPreferenceValue` or `.backgroundPreferenceValue`.

```swift
struct TextPreference: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = "default"
    static func reduce(value: inout String, nextValue: () -> String) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var readStringOfTextView: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextView()
                .onPreferenceChange(TextPreference.self) { value in
                    readStringOfTextView = value
                }
            Text(readStringOfTextView)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @State var stringOfText : String = "Hello, world!"

    var body: some View {
        Text(stringOfText)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .preference(key: TextPreference.self, value: stringOfText)
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said I already know the usage of State and Binding, . . .  TextView is not observe something! you put binding there! look my code please. I want to read the State of TextView, maybe the closer way and more logical way would be ObservableObject get shared between TextView and  ContentView, which someone can read or write, I am looking to find better way

Comment: Yes, ObservableObject would be the correct tool if you have state that you want multiple Views to all observe and share. You must not read other Views State. State is explicitly internal. Preferences work for this as well, but generally are not the right tool for the kind of thing you're describing. If it's "model-like" then you want an Observable.

Comment: So, that is why I asked this Question, I was not sure if there could or not could be a better way than ObservableObject method! when I am going to use ObservableObject, I am doing upside-down engineering to solve the issue, and in this case I am not using State but StateObject, So is it right to say State is not accessible from outside, but StateObject is!?! and can I say the best and right answer is StateObject?

Comment: StateObject gives a View ownership of something that would otherwise be an ObservedObject. It's a convenience because it means at the top-level View, you don't need to have the object passed in. But you still must not try to interrogate the StateObjects of child Views. "State" things are always private. Views never are the owners of state for higher-level Views (or other parts of the system). The best overview of how this works is from WWDC20: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/